# Change deploymen.toml for account suspension

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

My **deployment.toml**

```java
[identity_mgt]
inactive_account_suspention.enable_account_suspension = true
inactive_account_suspention.delays=1 // is it right?
inactive_account_suspention.account.disable.delay=2 is it right?
inactive_account_suspension.trigger_notifications_at = "06:20:00"
```

**Identity-event-properties** file

```java
suspension.notification.subscription.1=POST_AUTHENTICATION
suspension.notification.enable=true
suspension.notification.delays=30,45,60,75
suspension.notification.account.disable.delay=90
suspension.notification.trigger.time=06:20:00
```

**Questions**:

1. I have changed suspension delay in my **Idendity Provider** and my **trigger_notifications_at** in my **deployment.toml** (it is also changed in **identity-event-properties**). How i can change delays,disable.delay in **deployment.toml**,so it will change in **identity-event-properties**?
2. Is it possible to set minutes instead of days in **delays**? What is fastest way of getting suspension delay and disabled messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use the following configs to change  suspension.notification.account.disable.delay and suspension.notification.delays

```
[identity_mgt]
inactive_account_suspension.notify_when_inactive_for = 1
inactive_account_suspension.suspend_when_inactive_for= 2
```

File `<wso2is>/repository/resources/conf/default.json` contains the default values. You can use the property name defined in that file or check whether any key mapping is defined in `<wso2is>/repository/resources/conf/key-mappings.json` for a particular config.

For example: The default value of `suspension.notification.account.disable.delay` in identity-even.properties file is taken from `"identity_mgt.events.schemes.\u0027suspension.notification\u0027.properties.\u0027account.disable.delay\u0027": "90d"` in the `default.json` file. If you check on `key-mappings.json` you an find a keymapping as

```
"identity_mgt.inactive_account_suspension.suspend_when_inactive_for": "identity_mgt.events.schemes.\u0027suspension.notification\u0027.properties.\u0027account.disable.delay\u0027"
```

2. You can't change the unit defined in the property description, since the backend logic is written considering the user inputs the value in days.

Comment: Not getting suspend,notify messages.When the time of suspension starts? Does wso restarts suspension timer it when i reboot it?